# Hudson git failed to send out build failure email to

Tags: git, hudson

How to configure the git user.name to enable Hudson send out email to the user who commit code?

I just follow the standard way to configure the git user.name with "User Name (userid)", see below.

> git config --global user.name "Euler XXXX (euler)"
>
> git config --global user.email "euler.xxxx@server.com"

Then I commit the code to git repository, which trigger Hudson build. But it was failed to send out the email to me with email `euler.xxxx@server.com`.

See the Hudson log as below:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 10 15:05:51 CST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/74M
[INFO] ----

--------------------------------------------------------------------


**Failed to send e-mail to Euler XXXX (euler) because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured**
...
```

In Hudson configuration, I configured "`LDAP Email Lookup`", which provided by Hudson LDAP email plugin.

While if I configure the `user.name` with the `userid`, which is `userid` in my LDAP server, then the Hudson build can find email address.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the guy who wrote this [blog post](http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2011/01/hudson-git-plug-in-issues.html) managed to fix the problem you are having.  Although it doesn't look like it has made it into the plugin, so you have to compile the plugin yourself.

Comment: This has been merged into the plugin as of about a year ago. We're using an ancient version of the plugin, I'll have to see if I can convince someone to update it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to visit the "People" page (/people/) and add an email address for this user (at /user/{username}). The git config email address gets ignored by the git plugin.

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global` writes to global **~/.gitconfig file**.

Your problem comes from the fact that `~` used when you typed the `git config` is not the same than the `~` used by the user actually executing the Hudson job.

Check and make sure of the user home actually involved in that Hudson job execution.

Comment: Thanks! The hudson server is executed under oher user A for intergraion. while user B commit code. I just expect the email notify to user B.